# What is the reason for crashes caused by HeaderScrollingViewBehavior?

Tags: android

After rolling out the app to production, we get a high number of crash report. The crashed are caused by `HeaderScrollingViewBehavior`.

But, we're clueless on the actual root cause, as it doesn't point to any of our app code.

### java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline (RecyclerView.java:6023)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition (RecyclerView.java:5958)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition (RecyclerView.java:5954)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next (LinearLayoutManager.java:2226)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk (LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill (LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren (LinearLayoutManager.java:622)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1 (RecyclerView.java:3941)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout (RecyclerView.java:3705)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout (RecyclerView.java:4260)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:20962)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6276)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:325)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:261)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:20962)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6276)
  at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onLayout (ViewPager.java:1775)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:20962)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6276)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame (LinearLayout.java:1842)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical (LinearLayout.java:1686)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout (LinearLayout.java:1595)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:20962)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6276)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:325)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:261)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:20962)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6276)
  at com.google.android.material.appbar.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild (HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:148)
  at com.google.android.material.appbar.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild (ViewOffsetBehavior.java:41)
  at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild (AppBarLayout.java:1631)
  at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.setTopAndBottomOffset (AppBarLayout.java:1631)
  at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild (AppBarLayout.java:1631)
  at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout (CoordinatorLayout.java:898)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:20962)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6276)
  at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout (DrawerLayout.java:1231)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:20962)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6276)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:325)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:261)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:20962)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6276)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:325)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:261)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:20962)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6276)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:325)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:261)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:20962)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6276)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame (LinearLayout.java:1842)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical (LinearLayout.java:1686)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout (LinearLayout.java:1595)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:20962)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6276)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:325)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:261)
  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout (DecorView.java:880)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:20962)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:6276)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout (ViewRootImpl.java:3024)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:2532)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:1624)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:7926)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:1079)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:885)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:809)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:1065)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:891)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:207)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7470)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:524)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:958)
```

---

### exception.class.missing.*Unknown*: View Holder 2

```
exception.class.missing._Unknown_: View Holder 2
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.handleMissingPreInfoForChangeError (RecyclerView.java:4124)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep3 (RecyclerView.java:4048)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout (RecyclerView.java:3718)
  at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout (RecyclerView.java:4260)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:18804)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5951)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:323)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:261)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:18804)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5951)
  at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onLayout (ViewPager.java:1775)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:18804)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5951)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame (LinearLayout.java:1741)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical (LinearLayout.java:1585)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout (LinearLayout.java:1494)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:18804)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5951)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:323)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:261)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:18804)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5951)
  at com.google.android.material.appbar.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild (HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:148)
  at com.google.android.material.appbar.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild (ViewOffsetBehavior.java:41)
  at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild (AppBarLayout.java:1631)
  at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.setTopAndBottomOffset (AppBarLayout.java:1631)
  at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild (AppBarLayout.java:1631)
  at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout (CoordinatorLayout.java:898)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:18804)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5951)
  at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout (DrawerLayout.java:1231)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:18804)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5951)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:323)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:261)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:18804)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5951)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:323)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:261)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:18804)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5951)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:323)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:261)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:18804)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5951)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame (LinearLayout.java:1741)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical (LinearLayout.java:1585)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout (LinearLayout.java:1494)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:18804)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5951)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:323)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:261)
  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout (DecorView.java:888)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:18804)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5951)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout (ViewRootImpl.java:2659)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:2375)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:1526)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:7102)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:927)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:702)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:638)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:913)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6682)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1534)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1424)
```

Any idea on why such crashes happen? The crashes happen on Android 8.1 till Android 9. We are expecting more crashes coming in. But, we can hardly reproduce the crashes.

Our app is targeting API 28 with AndroidX.

Comment: I have been getting the same errors for some months. I am targetting API 29, and I am using R8 for release builds. Do you use R8/Proguard as well ? The "exception.class.missing.Unknown" looks somewhat like Proguard wrongfully removing some code. I have no idea why it would only affect some devices though.

Comment: Have same problems, any progress on this?

Comment: I am also getting this error when using custom recyclerview item decoration. Does anyone find the solution for this?

Comment: No solution???/?